# reCaptcha Invalid domain for site key key error

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, multisite

reCaptcha on the subsite mapped to custom domain showing invalid domain for site key error.

We are implementing a multisite solution in which our main site domain is http://www.oursite.net.

Our subsite has 2 types.
1) using the subfolder structure, so the URL is www.oursite.net/abc
2) mapped to a custom domain, so the URL is www.xyz.com

Each of our subsite has its own registration form which is associated with a recaptcha form powered by your solution.

For all subsites using the subfolder URL, the Recaptcha is working fine. See this screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MkIfM7frQBCYBAldkKZ0PAuSViNSSBc7/view?usp=sharing

For the ones mapped to the custom domains, we keep getting this Invalid Domain error. See this screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-R1RfH18RJATLAYbHYp7uLZ6ia66HmL8/view?usp=sharing

Before we apply the recaptcha to the subsites with custom domains, we have tried both of the following:
1) add the custom domain (xyz.com) to the reCaptcha setting for oursite.com under the Google Developer console.
2) create a new reCaptcha key for the custom domain (xyz.com) via the Google Developer console.

Each time, we copied and pasted the latest reCaptcha key to the plugin setting.

None of these 2 measures help.

Please advise.

Desired outcome: on the subsite mapped to custom domain, reCaptcha is rendered properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to implement reCAPTCHA Version 2.0 without verifying each domain:Visit https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/domain_validation

```
See the admin console and click the API key in question under 

"Your reCAPTCHA Sites". 

Then under "Advanced Settings", 

uncheck Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions
```

Comment: It is fixed. Thank you!